# how to merge an end anchor point with a path

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, anchor-point

I tried to unit and join the end anchor point with the path shown in the picture but I either get the paths interlocked or part of the drawing just disappear.

[image: the drawing I'm working on]

[image: close up where I want the merge to happen]

Comment: You can only join end points to other end points. You can only join endpoints of un-grouped paths. You can make Illustrator treat individual paths as one object by making it a compound path. (Object>Compound Path>Make).

Answer (score 0):

You can't merge it with a path. You can only join anchor points to other anchor points.

Anyway, there is no need to do that. There's nothing wrong with the paths just the way they are in your example. If your ultimate aim is to colour in the drawing, learn about the Live Paint functionality in Illustrator - there are tutorials online.